# Unable to connect to Mongo DB 6 from node application

Tags: node.js, mongodb

We are using two different environments for our app. One is the development and another is production.

For development, we use Mongo Atlas free instance with MongoDB v6.
And for production, we are using Mongo Atlas paid version with MongoDB v5.

Everything was working fine. But all of a sudden the development server stopped working and it's giving an error, but the production server is still working fine.

```
Process exited with code 1
(node:8810) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'count' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:8810) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'findOne' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:8810) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'remove' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:8810) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'updateOne' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:8810) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'SYSTEM_INDEX_COLLECTION' of module exports inside circular dependency
Uncaught MongoError MongoError: Unsupported OP_QUERY command: insert. The client driver may require an upgrade.
For more details see https://dochub.mongodb.org/core/legacy-opcode-removal
```

I tried to go through the steps in the link mentioned above, but no use.

I updated Mongoose and MongoDB on the server but no use. From the terminal, I am able to connect to the development instance DB, which is MongoDB v6.

Right now, we are not in a position to make v6 upgrade. So can anyone suggest a quick solution?

Comment: did u give a look at mongoose [issues](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues?q=Accessing+non-existent+property) section too

Comment: These changes are properly documented, see [Legacy Opcodes Removed](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/release-notes/6.0-compatibility/#legacy-opcodes-removed). You may update your driver used by the application.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: yes I did @cmgchess